# Animate two bullet lists in sync?

Tags: keynote

Given a side by side list of bullets, I can animate them to reveal bullet by bullet. But they will only animate one list at a time. For instance:

[image: example]

The list of one, two, three will go down point by point, then four, five six. I would like to reveal one and four at the same time, the two and five and finally three and six. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: create 3 tables that you sequently hide and show. first table with one row, second with two rows, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean. Can you clarify. I'm new to keynote.